# kwargs to python instance method

Tags: python

I need to pass a kwargs to a Python instance method but get the following error below.

```
class test(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Initializaed'

    def testmethod(self,**kwargs):
        for each in kwargs:
            print each



x = test()
x.testmethod({"name":"mike","age":200})
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AN\workspace\Scratch\Scratch\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    x.testmethod({"name":"mike","age":200})            
TypeError: testmethod() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Try `x.testmethod(**{"name": "mike", "age": 200})` or `x.testmethod(name="mike", age=200)`. You're currently passing a single dictionary as a positional argument, rather than aribitrary keyword arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
x.testmethod({"name":"mike","age":200})
```

This invokes `testmethod()` with two *positional arguments* - one is implicit (the object instance, i.e. `self`) and the other one is the dictionary you gave it.

To pass in keyword arguments, use the `**` operator for unpacking your dictionary into `key=value` pairs, like this:

```
x.testmethod(**{"name":"mike","age":200})
```

This translates to `x.testmethod(name='mike', age=200)` which is what you want. You can also read about argument unpacking in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).